# Centering only part of a sentence and ignoring the rest

Tags: horizontal-alignment, textwidth

Say I have some text that I want to center while the text that follows (in the same line) should be ignored for centering purposes. How do I achieve this in latex?

[image: Latex render of the code]

The second line in the image above should be centered like the first. The third line represents a trial-and-error hack using `\widthof`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{calc}

%text that matters
\newcommand{\ImportantPart}{This part should be centered }

%text that doesn't matter
\newcommand{\IgnoredPart}{\textcolor{red}{while this doesn't matter}}

\begin{document}
%push box to bottom, let page no serve as a visual centerline marker
\null\vfill
%draw a box for visual aid
\begin{tcolorbox}



%this is how the centering should be done, regardless of what follows the important part
%the \IgnoredPart isn't printed here to illustrate
\centering \ImportantPart\\

%this is what it prints out to be
%centering gets applied to the whole sentence
{\centering \ImportantPart}\IgnoredPart\\


%the trial and error hack using \hspace
%not perfect
\centering \hspace{\widthof{\IgnoredPart}}\ImportantPart \IgnoredPart\\





\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{calc}

%text that matters
\newcommand{\ImportantPart}{This part should be centered}

%text that doesn't matter
\newcommand{\IgnoredPart}{\makebox[0pt][l]{ \textcolor{red}{while this doesn't matter}}}

\begin{document}
%push box to bottom, let page no serve as a visual centerline marker
\null\vfill
%draw a box for visual aid
\begin{tcolorbox}



%this is how the centering should be done, regardless of what follows the important part
%the \IgnoredPart isn't printed here to illustrate
\centering \ImportantPart

%this is what it prints out to be
%centering gets applied to the whole sentence
 \ImportantPart\IgnoredPart

\ImportantPart

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Place things in a zero width box

[image]

Comment: thnx ... any way to handle overflow into margin for long `\IgnoredPart`? Maybe wrap to nextline center?

Comment: @lineage well not really, you get what you ask for. this specifies that the red text has zero width so tex has no knowledge if it overshoots the margins. There are other techniques one could use but they would be completely different answers. Wait a bit someone may post something.

Answer (score 1):

Set a duplicate of the unwanted part in a `\phantom` on the opposite side of the thing you want centred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% For reference
\usepackage{xcolor}

%text that matters
\newcommand{\ImportantPart}{This part should be centered}
%text that doesn't matter
\newcommand{\IgnoredPart}{\textcolor{red}{while this doesn't matter}}

\begin{document}

\centering
%this is how the centering should be done, regardless of what follows the important part
%the \IgnoredPart isn't printed here to illustrate
\ImportantPart

%this is what it prints out to be
%centering gets applied to the whole sentence
\ImportantPart~\IgnoredPart


% Using \phantom
\phantom{\IgnoredPart~}\ImportantPart~\IgnoredPart

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the `\rlap`command. Of course, it's up to you to check the final sentence does not overflow into the margin:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
%push box to bottom, let page no serve as a visual centerline marker
\null\vfill
%draw a box for visual aid
\begin{tcolorbox}

\centering This part should be centred \\

 \centering This longer part should be centred \rlap{\quad\color{red}this one be ignored}\\

\centering This part should be centred \rlap{\quad\color{red}this one be ignored too}\\

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thnx but the This of all sentences should align

Comment: Even if they don't have the same length? And also for the ignored part?

Comment: good point....the `this` of all `This part should be centered ` should align...so line 2 is an exception

Comment: It's simple to align the beginning *This* while centring the longest text: you juste have to put each sentence in an `\eqmakebox[some tag][l]   {…}` (from the `eqparbox` package).